# Code to select the PushButton using Tab Key

Tags: qt, widget, tabbar

I have designed the UI screen which consist a lot of push-buttons and I want to select or can say want to control application using tab key. When I select any particular key, it should change the color of that push-button accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the focus on using the tab key should work by default and the color of the buttons changes according to focus.

I tried to create a project with several buttons on *QMainWIndow* and it worked without any additional effort. I'm using Qt 5.15 with KDE on arch linux.

If you want to change the order of the buttons traversal, you can use the button that changes the designer mode in Qt Creator.

[image: reordering button in Qt Creator]

And if you want to change colors of the button, you should change the stylesheet of the button with css like code. [Here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html) you can see examples of stylesheet customization.

Comment: Yes I have worked on tab order but what I want to know is that how to change color of push-button when controlled by tab key. Like there is feature of keyEvent which can be used for the same. But it is not enabling tab key.

Comment: This is the small code which I have written

Comment: void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    
    ui->centralwidget->setStyleSheet("QPushButton { background-color: blue; }\n"
                                     "QPushButton:enabled { background-color: rgb(0,255,0); }\n");

}

Comment: Did you want to change the color on focus? Then you can change focus stylesheet like this `setStyleSheet("QPushButton:focus {  background-color: red; }")` somewhere in code (for example in constructor) or in ui editor mode of Qt Creator. If you want to change color of the button focused with tab only, then you need to override `focusNextPrevChild()` method of **QMainWindow** and implement your own focus change on tab key method in `keyPressEvent()`.